# On Duplicating div Inner Ids increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, clone

I duplicate Tr with id of clone and increment it: I want Ids within TR to increment e.g: One1, One2, One3 etc
Increament Id One Two Three /
e.g: One1, One2 etc to other as well

My HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Input</th>
        <th>Checkbox 1</th>
        <th>Checkbox 2</th>
        <th>Add More</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="clone" class="clone">
        <td class="form" data-label="Name"> <input id="One" type="text"> </td>
        <td data-label="Add"><input id="Two" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td data-label="Edit"><input id="Three" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td data-label="Edit"><button class="addmore"  onclick="duplicate();">Add More</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My JS :

```
function duplicate() {
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('clone');
    var count = 1;

    if (count < 20) {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.id = "clone" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        count++;
      var $address = $('.clone', '#One');
      address.attr('id', 'One' + rowNum);
    } else {
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2hecadf4/2/)**

**Question:**

I want to increment the innner Ids , How can I increment it ?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: I want to increment the innner Ids , How can I increment it ?